# Is placing an `autorun.inf` folder in a drive's root a good safety precaution?

Tags: windows, usb-drive

Is it possible for viruses to use Windows' `autorun.inf` mechanism to start their execution? If so, is placing an `autorun.inf` folder a good safety precaution? My reasoning is that it can help in one fo two ways:

- Best case scenario, the virus cannot write its own `autorun.inf` file because it is blocked by the folder.
- Worst case scenario, the virus deletes the folder and replaces it with its own `autorun.inf` file. The drive is now infected, but at least you can notice the folder is missing and you are aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it might help. Better yet, make your computer not to obey `autorun.inf` on removable drives (but assuming you plug your usb into another -infected- system, it can help noticing it).

There is a solution taking the next step, [USB Vaccine](http://www.pandasecurity.com/usa/homeusers/downloads/usbvaccine/), which creates a unwriteable, undeletable file with that name in your usb drive. It does so by marking it with some extra bits at low-level, so the normal fs aren't able to remove it (the program can *uninstall* it, of course). Virus are very unlikely to go down at such level just to remove an `autorun.inf`

But regardless of that, disable its execution. And remember that there are more ways of getting infected via usb than due to an `autorun.inf`.